# SAXReader() timeout

Tags: java, rss, sax

I'm having a SAXReader() to parse and read a RSS-feed. What I want to do is ensure that it wont try to read for a long period. I want to ensure that if the reader hasn't received a response or something within X seconds, it will abort.

My code:

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Document doc = reader.read(new URL(myURL));
```

This is inside a try/catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tweak the `URLConnection` by opening it manually:

```
URL myUrl = getURLToLoad();
URLConnection con = myUrl.openConnection()
con.setConnectTimeout(1000);
con.setReadTimeout(2000);
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
// parse in however you want
```